# Can't establish internet connection to my EC2 instance [deployed with terraform and 80 http port opened for ACL, Security Group, Internet GW]

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created an EC2 instance with terraform aws provider. The Instance is an Ubuntu server of free tier *t2.micro*.

Even though I have followed every Amazon guide about Network ACLs, Security Groups, Route tables, Internet gateways, I still cannot execute a simple command such as

`sudo apt-get update`

When I log in to my instance from ssh port (22) and execute the sudo command above, I receive back this message:

> 0% [Connecting to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com (52.15.159.198)]

Resources I have followed:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console#ec2-instance-connect-setup-security-group
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html#vpc-igw-internet-access
3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-rules
4. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#AddRemoveRules

And many SO questions.

*Note that I connect with **ssh** to port 22 and **ping** the public ip of ec2 instance. I have also created a route table which has an internet gateway attached to network interface.*

Network rules:

[image: inbound acl rules]

[image: outbound acl rules]

Security group rules:

[image: inbound sg rules]

[image: outbound sg rules]

Route table attached to my instance

[image]

My only concern is that the vpc I use has a main acl network (like a default) which is not the one I use (the one with the many rules in the screenshot above). However, the main route table guides to the correct subnet that is also attached to the correct acl network. I guess this is happening because in terraform I use the *aws_network_acl* resource and not the *aws_default_network_acl*.

Thus, my only concern might be that I have a wrong acl network attached to my vpc, however even that acl network has allowed all inbound - outbound traffic. So accessing http shouldn't impose a problem. Since I can't download anything from my ec2 instance, I believe that something else is the root of my problem.

Appreciate any help in advance.

[Terraform code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hngvs5DH7MeAOKNwdDkDwCg_y30AhOHR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please do not use images.

Comment: Do you think you could post the Terraform code that you used?

Comment: @MarkoE yeah I know it becomes TLDR, I will keep that note.

Comment: @Michael I will post the terraform code, but I warn you it's long. I will probably upload a txt saved in a my google drive

Comment: @Michael I have uploaded the terraform code

Comment: In general, it is a good idea to "Allow All" on Outbound security groups since you should trust the software running on the instance. It is also a good idea to leave the default "Allow All" settings on NACLs (both Inbound and Outbound) unless you have a very specific security need (eg creating a DMZ). It is one or both of these configurations that is blocking the outbound connections necessary for your commands to complete.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you it's basically in the NACL. I will try your approach tomorrow and keep you noted. Besides, it was Amazon documentation that made me to specify inbound ruling for tcp port in nacl level. By the way in the outbound level I allow all the traffic (check my screenshots)

Comment: Your screenshot for Outbound Security Group rules shows only certain ports listed. The default is normally "Allow All" on _every_ port. This can be useful for some services that use multiple port ranges (eg FTP). The fact that you can connect to the instance, but the instance is having trouble connecting outwards suggests the problem lies in either the Outbound Security group, or in the NACLs.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yeah it was basically to allow *All inbound traffic* in my NACL resource. But still I don't understand why I couldn't connect to the internet in the first place. Since I had already opened port 80 (http) for all traffic. Two questions on this matter: 1) Is it safe enough to open all traffic in acl networks, 2) Since http (80) didn't work, is there any other port that if opened in acl network would have solved my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Security Groups are stateful.** This means that if traffic is permitted in one direction, then a return response is allowed to come back in. For example, you could open port 80 to Inbound traffic and the web server could respond to the request even if there was no Outbound rule in the Security Group.

In contrast, **Network Access Control Lists (NACLs) are stateless.** This means that sending a request in one direction does *not* automatically permit a response in the other direction.

When a web request is made to the Internet to a web server, it goes to port 80 on the remote server. However, the return traffic does *not* come on port 80. Rather, your request to the remote port 80 **comes from a random port** on your own computer. Therefore, the NACL must permit return traffic to that random port. This is probably what blocked the response to your web request to download the software.

I used to find this concept very hard to understand. I always thought that requests going *to* port 80 must *come* from my port 80. But that's not how it works. Web requests to the Internet will *never* come from port 80 because that port is associated with the web server on that computer. It actually makes sense because, for example, let's say that Computer A opens two tabs in a web browser and sends a request to `google.com:80` and `facebook.com:80`. The return traffic from each server needs to come back to a different port so that the browser knows which response to display in each tab.

Yes, it is safe to open all NACL ports. In traditional networks, security was only enforced in routers *between* subnets. This security is mirrored in NACLs. However, the Cloud provides an additional layer of security by using Security Groups that act as **firewalls on each resource individually**. This is more powerful than traditional network security. Thus, it is quite normal to permit all traffic at the NACL level unless you have a very specific security need, such as creating a DMZ or blocking a particular type of traffic entering the network.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer and also for responding to my questions.Briefly, my final solution has allowed *all traffic* for inbound and outbound routes in my ACL network. And 80 http traffic only for the outbound routes of Security group. The inbound rules of Security group include only the SSH traffic coming from my two explicit ip addresses.